# Different operation conditionally at single query - MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am trying to do such thing like:

- Set `field` to `0` if this `field` is greater than `10` or `increment` by `1` if not.

Is it possible? I can do for sure:

- if `field` equals to `10` set `0` (Updates with Aggregation Pipeline),

but I don't know if I am able to increment instead if is less than `10`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$cond` to apply different logic based on condition
- `$gte` to check if the current value is greater of equal to 10
- `$sum` to increment current value by 1

```
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "counter": {
        "$cond": {
          if: {
            "$gte": [
              "$counter",
              10
            ]
          },
          then: 0,
          else: {
            "$sum": [
              "$counter",
              1
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
],
{
  multi: true
})
```

[Working example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/gmCxil3IyFF)